# Oscillations of an Energy Eigenstate

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Energy eigenstates of a 1-dimensional particle are given by solutions to differential equations of the form
$$
\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{d^2}{dx^2} + V(x) \right) \psi(x) = E\psi(x)
$$
where $V$ is the potential, $\psi$ is the energy eigenstate, and $E$ is the energy eigenvalue.

In introductory (and even fairly advanced) texts on quantum mechanics, the following facts are asserted without proof:

1. The set $\{E \in \mathbb{R} : E \text{ is an energy eigenvalue and } E < \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} V(x) \}$ is a discrete subset of the reals bounded below by $\inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}} V(x)$.
2. If the discrete energy eigenvalues above are listed in ascending order as $E_0, \ldots, E_n$ and have corresponding energy eigenstates $\psi_0, \ldots, \psi_n$, then $\psi_n$ will have $n + 1$ local maxima.

The above results are often stated with less precision, and sometimes even conflict with each other.

What statements like 1 and 2 above are actually true, and how does one go about proving them?

Comment: See Courant & Hilbert volumes.

Comment: These hold for potentials that drop off rapidly at $\infty$, but in general there can be [eigenfunctions with an infinite number of maxima](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/350394/85443).

Comment: You have been wasting time on bad texts. Go to [Messiah, Quantum Mechanics, v I , Ch III, sec 8](https://archive.org/details/QuantumMechanicsVolumeI/page/n59).

Comment: This reference explains the discrete energies. Does it explain the number of oscillations somewhere else?

Comment: In part, but I also want to know why the eigenfunctions in the discrete spectrum oscillate a number of times that corresponds to the energy level. For example, the bound states $\psi_n$ of the quantum harmonic oscillator have $n + 1$ critical points. I was told this is a general phenomenon in my quantum mechanics course, but I've never seen a proof of it. Of course it's entirely possible it's just something special about the quantum harmonic oscillator, and I was misled.

Comment: Alright, I'll look through it again. I might not have gotten to that part, or I might not have noticed it. The text was just slightly over my head, but it seems like a good Quantum book worth reading. For reference, I've only seriously studied out of Sakurai and Shankar, both of whom I found lacking on this point.

Comment: Ch III, §12 ... "If one arranges the eigenstates in order of increasing energies $\epsilon _1,\epsilon_2,..,\epsilon_n,...$, the eigenfunctions likewise fall in the order of increasing number of nodes; the *n* th eigenfunction has *n-1* nodes between each of which the following eigenfunctions all have at least one node."

Comment: This is elmentary 1D Sturm Liouville theory. Courant-Hilbert, as mentioned above, do a bang-up job, but Messiah gives a sweet hands-on vulgarization of it. If it is over your head, I don't believe it can be simplified further. Illustrate it and accept it.

Comment: Of course I will try to read and understand Messiah's text (when I find the time). But what can I say, one man's elementary 1D Sturm Liouville theory is another man's index theory.